# How do I use an InfiniBand network with Dask?

Tags: python, dask, infiniband

I have a cluster with a high performance network (InfiniBand).  However when I set up my Dask scheduler and workers, performance doesn't seem to be as fast as I would expect.  How can I tell Dask to use this network?

*Disclaimer: I'm just asking this question so that I can answer it.  It has become a frequently asked question*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of dask.distributed version 1.16.3 you can specify a network interface to the `dask-scheduler` and `dask-worker` executables using the `--interface` keyword like the following:

```
dask-scheduler --interface ib0 --scheduler-file ~/my.cluster.yaml
dask-worker --interface ib0 --scheudler-file ~/my.cluster.yaml
```

In the code example above I have assumed that your infininband network interface is called `ib0`.  You can check this by asking your IT department or by inspecting the output of `ifconfig`

```
$ ifconfig
lo          Link encap:Local Loopback                       # Localhost
            inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
            inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
eth0        Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX   # Ethernet
            inet addr:192.168.0.101
            ...
ib0         Link encap:Infiniband                           # Fast InfiniBand
            inet addr:172.42.0.101
```

Comment: I use --interface ib0 but seems Dask still goes to eth0. How can I debug it? (distributed version 1.21.1. also working with my system admin). Thanks!